# Does Apache Jena support reasoning over OWL restrictions?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, rdfs, reasoning

The capabilities of Jena's OWL reasoner listed [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#owl) would seem to imply that Jena supports inference over restriction classes.

However, I am not observing this to be true. Specifically, I have an entity that is detected to be of a particular class, even though it's missing a property which a restriction with a minCardinality indicates must be present.

However, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, my OWL is a bit rusty.

My data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns      = "http://www.example.com/people#"
         xml:base   = "http://www.example.com/people#"
         xmlns:owl  = "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
         xmlns:rdf  = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:rdfs = "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:xsd  = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="name">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Person"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="xsd:string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="age">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Person"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="xsd:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>

    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Person">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#name"/>
                <owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:cardinality>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#age"/>
                <owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:cardinality>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>

    <!-- Is a person, because it's got a name and age -->
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="#john">
        <name>John</name>
        <age rdf:datatype="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">42</age>
    </rdf:Description>

    <!-- Should not be a person, because it's missing an age -->
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="#zeus">
        <name>Zeus</name>
    </rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

My Code:

```java
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("hello world");

        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);

        model.read("src/main/resources/sample.owl");

        String queryString =
                "PREFIX ppl:  <http://www.example.com/people#>" +
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                "SELECT ?obj " +
                "WHERE {" +
                "  ?obj rdf:type ppl:Person ." +
                "}";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
        qe.close();   
    }
```

This outputs:

```
------------
| obj      |
============
| ppl:john |
| ppl:zeus |
------------
```

I would not expect `ppl:zeus` to be an instance of `Person`, because it does not satisfy the minCardinality restriction on age.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here? Is reasoning around `rdfs:domain` overriding the reasoning around the restriction class?

Comment: In Protege, do Pellet and HermiT infer `ppl:zeus rdf:type ppl:Person`?

Comment: Good idea. It turns out that Pellet _does_ return the same results. So I guess it's safe to assume that the problem is in my modeling rather than in the software.

Comment: I guess, Jena recognizes `:name` and `:age` as object properties. In Protege, Pellet and HermiT behaves differently, too. [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/WkyJz6qG) works for me in Protege both with Pellet and HermiT.

Comment: Thank you. I think the reason that one works is because it doesn't specify rdfs:domain or rdfs:range on the :name or :age properties.

Comment: This is obvious ([`rdfs2`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdfs-entailment-informative)), but there are other problems in your ontology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation for this is actually because I made a rookie mistake in thinking about OWL and RDF inference.

The simple explanation (as pointed out in the comments) is that the `rdfs:domain` on the property is *sufficient* for the inferencer to decide that the entity is a `Person`. If an entity is the subject of a `name` then it is an instance of `Person`, Q.E.D.

This leads to another question, however. The restriction class clearly states that it is *not* a person unless it has both a `name` and an `age`. So why isn't this a logical inconsistency? I have one piece of data that says Zeus *is* a `Person`, and another piece of data that says he's *not*, don't I?

Well, no. Because even though I've encountered it many times before, I once again tripped over the Open World model of reasoning. Which is that all inferencing occurs with the assumption that you don't actually have all the facts, and that things *might* be true even if the system hasn't explicitly *asserted* them to be true.

In other words, just because my data doesn't explicitly state that Zeus has an `age`, doesn't mean he doesn't. Someone else could come along and assert an age at any time.

As such, in general, `minCardinality` constraints can't really be enforced or checked via open-world reasoning.

`maxCardinality` is a different story, and does result in an inconsistent ontology error in a similar situation.